# Talend Open studio - tRestClient - POST webservice call

Tags: web-services, post, odata, talend

I would like to be able to insert data using a POST webservice.
I can retrieve data perfectly well with a GET webservice, but POST is impossible...
Here is my error:

[image: Img]

I'm using the tRestBody component to import my body values:

[image: Img]

Is this the right way to go?

Comment: Looks like your web service doesn't support POST. Are you able to call to get data using POST using a tool other than Talend ?

Comment: Hello, I tried from postman with a POST call and there was no problem.

Comment: What does your body ultimately look like? Have you output it to console so you can see what is being passed in?

Comment: Strangely enough, I think the problem comes from the body... but I don't know how to display it in the "tLogRow" component. Could you give me an idea?

Comment: If you are using JSON , the name of your body should be "string" (same name as in the input schema of tRESTClient component) otherwise it won't work. Also, if it worked with postman, check if postman added some headers/parameters automatically to make it work.